# GIMP not exporting personal channel

Tags: gimp, export, filter, channel

I have created an image with a parchment-like effect. I achieved that creating a personal channel and applying to it the filter `Render > Noise > Solid noise`. I then painted on different layers what I needed without problems.

The problem came out when I exported the image. The output file doesn't keep the filter and I only get a plain color:

[image: input-output comparison]

I exported the image in some of the most used formats (png, jpg, pdf, gif)  and edited the exporting options without results.

How can I export my file keeping the parchment effect?

*If more informations are needed please ask for them and consider that I don't know much about the graphics design world.*

---

### Update 1

I'm adding some informations as required by @xenoid. To keep it simple, the following screenshots are from a "MWE" image with the same settings as the original one - which is rather complex - that behaves the same.

The following screenshots (click to enlarge) are, from the left to the right, the layers list, what GIMP shows to me and what I get when I export the image.

[image: background, normal and overlay]


[image: drawings on parchment-like background]


[image: non parchment-like drawings and only the ones in normal mode]

I confirm that the image is color-indexed and that I export it through `File > Export...` (or `File > Export As...`).

### Update 2

Image converted to RGB mode (`Image > Mode > RGB`). Something better - now I see the overlay layer - but I still don't have the noise channel.

[image: non parchment-like drawings but both normal and overlay layer]

### Update 3

"MWE" image available [here](https://send.firefox.com/download/396b4a0498a022eb/#phnuUDQcY7gJcMOytpuBTw).

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your layers list (possibly with bigger previews), tell if the image is color-indexed (indicated in the title bar) and confirm that you export using `File>Export`?

Comment: In color indexed mode the opacity is "binary" (all opaque o all transparent, norhing in between) so as a first step I would convert to RGB mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "a personal channel"?  Do you mean you added a custom channel in the channels panel?  Also what is an MWE image?  Any chance you could share the XCF file?

Comment: @BillyKerr By "personal channel" I mean I added it through `〈 Channels panel 〉 > 〈 right click 〉 > New Channel...`. By "MWE image" I mean I'm not posting the original image I'm having problems with (it has several layers and also contains some personal informations I don't want to share), but a "reduced" version that reproduces my problem. Yes, I can share the XCF file - how do I do that?

Comment: You can upload the image to a file sharing service such as onedrive or dropbox, and provide a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your XCF file.

PNG and JPEG don't support additional channels. They are RGBa (4 channels) for PNG, and RGB (3 channels) for JPEG. Any additional channels you add will be completely ignored on export to these formats.

To add a texture to an existing image, don't add it on a channel. Instead add it on a new layer, and then change the blending mode to Multiply, and perhaps reduce the opacity of the layer a little.

Example:

[image]